# Web2py: is it dangerous to display request.args[0]

Tags: web2py

From a web2py controller, I'm returning something like:

raise HTTP(404,"Sorry, could not find {}".format(request.args[0]))

But is that dangerous? What if someone calls the page with a malicious args string? Could they inject html into my return page and construct a page on my server that contains their html content? What if they inject a huge amount of data into args[0] - will it DoS my server?

Comment: *"will it DoS my server?"* Try it? (if you're on LAN). Wouldn't you get an `IndexError` if there's no 0th element in `request.args`?

Comment: re IndexError - I'm trapping this in a try-catch block, so that's no problem.

Comment: I've just seen that 127.0.0.1:8000/mypage.json/<malicious> returns an invalid url, so some of my worries seem unfounded

Comment: @jDo, the request is being handled by the web2py framework -- dispatching does not work as you describe. /mypage.json would not refer to a static JSON file but would point to a controller that generates a JSON response (and would potentially read the remaining segments of the URL path as arguments to be used in creating the response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be safe, just do:

```
raise HTTP(404, xmlescape("Sorry, could not find {}".format(request.args[0])))
```

`xmlescape()` will escape the text, so there will be no HTML/JS for the browser to display.